# Creating a Common function catering to different logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a method `DoSomeFunc()` in `Common.cs` file which is called by three different methods of ClassA.cs.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void FuncA()
    { 
        var test1 = common.DoSomeFunc(false);
    }

    public void FuncB()
    {
        var test2 = common.DoSomeFunc(true);
    }
   
    public void FuncC()
    { 
        var test3 = common.DoSomeFunc(false);
    }
}
```

The function FuncB() needs to do additional logic in the middle of DoSomeFunc() . So the coding I am trying is this way.

```
public void DoSomeFunc(bool isRequestFromFuncB)
{

...
...

#region isRequestFromFuncB
#endregion

...
...
}
```

I can completely rewrite DoSomeFunc() to cater to FuncB but most of the functionality will be same for all the classes.

If by introducing a parameter specific in `Dosomething()` to cater `FuncB` am I violating any of the **SOLID** principles in C#. Can this be refactored in any better way?

Comment: If you have a common method that all of sudden has to become aware of it's specific implementations it's starting to no longer become common. Can you give some more details about what this DoSomeFunc() needs to do and specifically what it needs to do when FuncB calls it?

Comment: Not sure if that breaks SOLID specifically, but it already feels bad in your stomach and that should be enough to rethink it. Now to the topic: Lets say DoSomeFunc consists of parts A, B and C, of which only "FuncB" must invoke part B. So, my first attempt would be to split the Function into A, B, and C, so FuncA, FuncB and FuncC are free to call, whatever they need of the functionality provided.

Comment: I don't think what you have is a big deal. I would in fact make the parameter optional, so anything but B making the call would not have to pass/provide the true/false. You could also use a typed over-load, and thus based on the type of var you pass, it would determine which routines are called, but that would ONLY make sense if you willing to make a whole copy of the routine, and then it could call the routine and then do the B code part. o, consider a overload with the same name + a passed flag. Thus, any pass of true runs a different routine.